# Oracle update skip locked with dependency on other rows

Tags: multithreading, oracle, oracle11g

For multithreaded env in our application we implemented oracle skip locked where no two threads pick up the same record in the database for processing(We add 'waiting' to 'working' flag).

Now, we have a modification where if two records in the database which are queued for processing have the same ID(workid) should not picked up the same time.(i.e - the other record status should not be updated to WORKING if already one record has a flag was 'WORKING'
Can someone help as to how this can be achieved?

Below is the procedure for the same where single record is locked without comparison.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE DEQUEUE_MANAGER(
    v_managerName IN Queue.manager%TYPE,
    v_workid IN VARCHAR2,
    v_key OUT NUMBER,
    v_datatablekey OUT Queue.DATA_TABLE_KEY%TYPE,
    v_tasktype OUT Queue.TASK_TYPE%TYPE,
    v_no_of_attempts OUT Queue.ATTEMPT%TYPE,
    v_result OUT NUMBER,
    v_error_desc OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
    v_recordrow Queue%ROWTYPE;
    v_qeuuestatus  VARCHAR2(255);
    v_updatedstaus VARCHAR2(255);
    CURSOR c IS 
        select * 
        from QUEUE  
        WHERE MANAGER =v_managerName 
        AND STATUS =v_qeuuestatus 
        AND workid=v_workid 
        AND DATE_RELEASE<=SYSDATE 
    FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED;
BEGIN
    v_result      := -1;
    v_qeuuestatus :='WAITING';
    v_updatedstaus:='WORKING';
    v_tasktype :='';
    v_datatablekey:=-1;
    v_key:=-1;
    v_error_desc:='No Data Found';
    v_no_of_attempts:=0;
    OPEN c;
    FOR i IN 1..1 LOOP
        FETCH c INTO v_recordrow;
        EXIT WHEN c%NOTFOUND;
        select v_recordrow.key into v_key 
        from QUEUE 
        where key = v_recordrow.key 
        for update;

        UPDATE Queue 
        SET STATUS=v_updatedstaus 
        WHERE KEY=v_recordrow.key;
        COMMIT;
        v_datatablekey:=v_recordrow.data_table_key;
        v_tasktype    := v_recordrow.task_type;
        v_no_of_attempts := v_recordrow.attempt;
        v_result      := 0;
        IF (v_no_of_attempts IS NULL) THEN
            v_no_of_attempts:=0;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE c;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
            v_datatablekey:=-1;
            v_tasktype:='';
            v_key:=-1;
            v_no_of_attempts:=0;
            v_result    :=-1;
            v_error_desc:='No Rows Found';      
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
              DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Exception Occurred');
              v_datatablekey:=0;
              v_tasktype:='';
              v_key:=0;
              v_no_of_attempts:=0;
              v_result     := -2;
              v_error_desc := SQLERRM;
              ROLLBACK;
END;
```

Comment: @shmosel edited

Comment: Can the same value of `workid` have different values of `queue status` or `manager`? Does that have any bearing on the locking rules?

Comment: @APC all the values are same initially. we just update the status from 'WAITING' to 'WORKING' so that the record doesn't get picked again and suggests its already working. I has no locking rules.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of the FOR UPDATE syntax is to lock records we want to update at some point in the future. We want to get the records now so that we can be sure our subsequent update won't fail because another session has locked the records.

That's not what your code does. Instead it selects the record, updates it and then issues a commit. The commit ends the transaction, which *releases the lock*. Your process would work the same without the FOR UPDATE.

Now we have your additional requirement: if a queued record for a given `workid` is being processed no other record for the same `workid` can be processed by another session. You say that all instances  of a `workid` have the same values of `queue status` or `manager`. So that means the initial SELECT FOR UPDATE grabs all the records you want to lock. The snag is the SKIP LOCK allows other sessions to update any other records for that `workid` (only the first record is actually locked because that's the only one you've updated). Not that it matters sd the commit releases those locks.

The simplest solution would be to remove the SKIP LOCKED and the COMMIT. That would keep all the related records locked up until your processing transaction commits. But this may create further problems elsewhere.

Concurrent programming is really hard to get right. It's an architectural problem; you can't solve it at the level of an individual program unit.

Comment: *Concurrent programming is really hard to get right. It's an architectural problem; you can't solve it at the level of an individual program unit.*  Indeed.  That stored procedure looks like an attempt to paper over a fundamental design problem.  Why is an RDBMS being used as some sort of queuing mechanism in the first place?  And why is a horribly complex stored procedure even thought to be necessary? In my experience, *adding* code like that comes from an effort to address *symptoms* of a problem: "This doesn't work, so we need to **ADD** more code."  Usually it doesn't work too well.

Comment: @andrewherle -I think it is perfectly reasonable for a database to have a queue to manage its background processes. Why not? But I have questions when people implement their own queuing mechanisms instead of using Oracle's built-in AQ solution. That often indicates wider problems (lack of Oracle experience, truculent DBA, overweening architect). YMMV

Comment: @APC I might have to rethink of the architecture.use case was we have a multithreaded java program which picks up one record from queue and processes.Used code synchronization so that no two thread have the same record resulting in deadlocks.to tackle that,we created a oracle skip locked procedure as above to let oracle take care of it that's why the skip locked. since one thread is assigned one record so it was updating single record at a time and returning the rowId for processing.In the context, of this requirement I believe now we have to think of a feasible solution and not add complexity